# find the area of ​a triangle along the variables of the straight line a b c

Tags: math, language-agnostic

I have input coefficients for a straight line ax + by + c. I find the x and y coordinates to find the area of ​​a right triangle that is formed by a line through the x and y axes. But on the test if a = 1 b = 1 c = -2
The area will be 0.5, not 2.

How to fix it?

```
a = int(input())
b = int(input())
c = int(input())

y = 0*a + b + c
x = a + 0*b + c
sAbc = 1/2 * a*b
print(sAbc)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question should be asked on Math stackoverflow, because there are issues with the math.

First, let us compute the y-intercept:

```
a*0 + b*y + c = 0
y = - c/b
```

(we would deal with vertical and horizontal lines later)
Similarly, we compute the x-intercept:

```
a*x + b*0 + c = 0
x = - c/a
```

Finally, the area is

```
# A = abs(0.5 * x * y) = abs(0.5 * (-c/a) * (-c/b)) = abs(0.5 * c * c / a / b)
A = abs(0.5 * c * c / a / b)
```

However, we need to deal with vertical and horizontal lines separately.

```
if a == 0 or b == 0:
   print(0)
else:
   print(abs(0.5 * c * c / a / b))
```

Answer (score 1):

You are using the wrong formula.

```py
a = int(input())
b = int(input())
c = int(input())
area = abs((c^2)/(a*b))/2
print(area)
```

Comment: When entering test 2 -1 2 the area is 0, not 1.0

Comment: How would it be 0?

Comment: When calculating the area where a = 2 b = -1 c = 2

Comment: `area` in the formula above is zero only if `c^2` is zero. `c^2` is zero if and only if `c=0`. Maybe, a typo @ГыггыгФидолобабович?

Comment: @ГыггыгФидолобабович The area will be 0 if at least one of ```a,b,c``` is 0